# Numpy submatrix(selected random index) calculation performance

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I tried to calculate the sub-matrix using Numpy.

The shape of matrices are

A : (15000, 100)

B : (15000, 100)

B_ : (3000, 100)

C : (100, 100)

```
sample_index = np.random.choice(np.arange(int(15000*0.2)), size=int(int(15000*0.2)), replace=False)
```

and the first code is

```
for ki in range(100):
    self.A[sample_index, k] += B_[:, k] - np.dot(self.A[sample_index, : ], C[:, k])
```

which only use sub matrix sliced from sample_index

and the second code is

```
for k in range(100):
    self.A[:, k] += B[:, k] - np.dot(self.A[:, : ], C[:, k])
```

which use all matrix.

But the calculation time of first code is slower than second code.

Do you know any reason or any solutions to speed-up?

Comment: Try `A[:3000, k]` instead; sliced indexing is faster than array indexing (basic v advanced indexing).

Comment: Why the look on `k`?  Why not `A[:,:] += B - np.dot(A, C)`?

Comment: Actually, I want to select random index
sample_index = np.random.choice(np.arange(int(15000*0.2)), size=int(15000*0.2), replace=False)
and
sample_index = np.arange(int(15000*0.2)) is just for test

Comment: In any case there's a trade off.  Indexing reduces the size of the calculation, but takes time itself.

Comment: As an aside, I think `sample_index=np.random.permutation(int(15000*.2))` would be faster than your first step

Comment: @DanielForsman yes I want to calculate only some sample rows.

Comment: Yeah, I'm realizing that.  You probably want your first line to be `sample_index = np.random.choice(np.arange(15000), size=int(int(15000*0.2)), replace=False)` then, or your'e only selecting a random shuffle of the first 3000 indices.

Comment: In my time tests, the indexed calculations are faster.  About 20% faster in the `k` loop case  2-3x for the non-loop version.  The randomness of `sample_index` doesn't make much difference in times.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually copying the input matrix. If you are just reading the input, you don't have to copy it.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10000).reshape(100, 100)
b = np.random.rand(10000).reshape(100, 100)
i = list(range(10))
a_sub0 = a[:10] # view
a_sub1 = a[i] # copying

# you can change the original matrix from the view
a_sub0[0, 0] = 100
(a[0, 0] == 100.0) and (a_sub1[0, 0] != 100.0) # True
```